MySql searching in JSON object with array with objects on specific property value
I have a table 'sometable' with a JSON field named 'jsonval', which contains a JSON object with the property 'programs' that contains an array of objects with the property 'id'
I want to search for records that contain jsonval.programs.id = 14
The following query works:
SELECT id, jsonval, JSON_EXTRACT(jsonval, '$.programs[*].id') FROM `sometable` 
WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(jsonval, '$.programs[*].id') LIKE '%"14"%';

because JSON_EXTRACT(jsonval, '$.programs[*].id') results in the string representation of the array holding the id's, i.e.: ["14","26"]
But there should be a more elegant solution, maybe using JSON_CONTAINS?

The best solution would probably be to create some other table and store the data contained in the JSON in that as normal data. Trying to search for things inside JSON in a database is just bad practice and will never be "elegant".

Edit: I wrote this answer before the OP revealed that they are using MariaDB 10.6, not MySQL. I'll leave it here for the benefit of readers who are using MySQL.

This is the current solution. MySQL 8.0.17 or later support the MEMBER OF predicate.
SELECT * FROM sometable
WHERE 14 MEMBER OF (jsonval->'$.programs');

This is better than using JSON_CONTAINS() because you can create a multi-valued index on the array (also requires MySQL 8.0.17).
ALTER TABLE sometable ADD KEY ((CAST(jsonval->'$.programs' AS UNSIGNED ARRAY)));

EXPLAIN
SELECT * FROM sometable
WHERE 14 MEMBER OF (jsonval->'$.programs');

The EXPLAIN shows that it uses the index:
+----+-------------+-----------+------------+------+------------------+------------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table     | partitions | type | possible_keys    | key              | key_len | ref   | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-----------+------------+------+------------------+------------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | sometable | NULL       | ref  | functional_index | functional_index | 9       | const |    1 |   100.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-----------+------------+------+------------------+------------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------+

In general I think anytime you need to reference a JSON column in your WHERE clause, you're better off storing data in normal rows and columns. Writing queries for JSON data results in more complex queries and some cases cannot be optimized.

I tried this solution, but did not work. Took a look at the engine and it's not MySql but MariaDB 10.6. I found that MariaDB supports JSON_VALUE: SELECT id, jsonval FROM sometable WHERE JSON_VALUE(jsonval, '$.programs[*].id') = 14;

@Overbeeke MariaDB and MySQL are indeed different products. In particular, they both implemented support for JSON after MariaDB forked from MySQL, and their JSON features are not fully compatible. Your question mentioned MySQL and was tagged mysql, so I assumed you were using MySQL.

I think UsingJSON_CONTAINS can make your query more explicit and potentially faster by avoiding string-based operations like LIKE.
   SELECT id, jsonval
    FROM sometable
    WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(jsonval->'$.programs[*].id', '14');


JSON_CONTAINS() will do a table-scan, the same as LIKE, so it  must examine every row in the table. If you run this query on a table with 1 million rows, or the query with LIKE, the performance will be very similar. The number of rows examined is a greater influence on performance cost, and the type of comparison makes less of a difference.
